# i can't run my project (error file included) android

Tags: java, android

When I try to run my project, it gives me an error file, I don't know how to fix it, if someone understands what the error file is telling me, please help. Thank you.

What I already tried:

- changing compiling mode
- android tools>fix project properties
- restarting eclipse

Error file:

```
# Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=8184, tid=10384
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000006dd800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=10384, stack(0x0000000002080000,0x0000000002180000)]

Stack: [0x0000000002080000,0x0000000002180000]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00000000006dd800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=10384, stack(0x0000000002080000,0x0000000002180000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.009 loading class 0x0000000002270a20 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x00000000022305a0 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x00000000022308a0
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x000000000b48f4a0
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x000000000b48f4a0 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x000000000b48ece0
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x000000000b48ece0 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x00000000022c7be0
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x00000000022c7be0 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x00000000022308a0 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000007f6ca630000 - 0x000007f6ca664000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x000007fc10f10000 - 0x000007fc110d0000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x000007fc0f1c0000 - 0x000007fc0f2f6000     C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x000007fc0d3f0000 - 0x000007fc0d4e3000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fc0feb0000 - 0x000007fc0ff8e000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fc0d770000 - 0x000007fc0d8bc000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fc0ae80000 - 0x000007fc0b0ea000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16579_none_418ab7ef718b27ef\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fc0f6e0000 - 0x000007fc0f785000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fc0f790000 - 0x000007fc0f7d8000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fc0d990000 - 0x000007fc0dad5000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007fc0eee0000 - 0x000007fc0f021000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fc0f370000 - 0x000007fc0f3a9000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fc0edc0000 - 0x000007fc0eed6000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000068a70000 - 0x0000000068b41000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000068300000 - 0x0000000068a1f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fc05280000 - 0x000007fc05289000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fc09110000 - 0x000007fc09130000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fc0f030000 - 0x000007fc0f037000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000007fc0f7e0000 - 0x000007fc0f838000     C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fc090d0000 - 0x000007fc09103000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x000007fc0d5b0000 - 0x000007fc0d5b9000     C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fc0d3a0000 - 0x000007fc0d3ef000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x000007fc0d130000 - 0x000007fc0d152000     C:\windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x0000000069590000 - 0x000000006959f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000068a40000 - 0x0000000068a68000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x00000000682e0000 - 0x00000000682f5000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar 
java_command: com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\DDS Utilities;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
USERNAME=jordi
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200 

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8246176k(4395516k free), swap 9525072k(4627160k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_09-b05), built on Sep 24 2012 21:45:04 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sat Mar 01 13:37:17 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that one of your layout sheets contains an error. Maybe you used a control, that is not contained in your API level.